# Can Congress create new US dollars without also increasing the national debt?

Tags: united-states

As far as I understand, the CARES Act and other stimulus programs are funded by increasing the [National Debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_debt_of_the_United_States). But is it possible to just "print money" without creating any debt? If so, why doesn't the US government do this?

Answer (score 3):

The US government can but the levers to control the rate of money creation, i.e. monetary policy, are primarily held by the central bank (the Fed) not Congress.  The Fed could allow money to be created faster but that would, naturally, lead to higher inflation (I am omitting various caveats for simplicity here-- if you want a rigorous explanation, that would be a question for the economics stack).  If there is more money in the system, each dollar will tend to be worth less than it was previously.  That in turn will tend to counteract some of the benefit of the stimulus program.  If you have $1,000 and the government gives you another $1,000 so you have $2,000 but the Fed allows inflation to reduce the purchasing power of your $2,000 to what $1,000 bought prior to the stimulus, you're no better off for having received the stimulus money and are unlikely to go out and spend the money in a way that will actually stimulate the economy.

This is, more or less, the case for all countries that borrow money in their home currency-- monetary policy is handled by the country's central bank.  If a country doesn't have independent control over their monetary policy either because they have pegged their currency to a more stable country's currency (lots of places peg the local currency to the US dollar for example) or because they are part of a currency union like the EU, then the country's government can't choose to inflate away their debt because it's denominated in a currency they don't control.

Comment: If the government borrows $1000, that's $1000 that someone was ready to invest in the economy, but is no longer available to be borrowed by someone needing it, so that also counteracts some of the benefits of the stimulus program.

Comment: As an aside and without going too far in the weeds, we know money printing does not inherently lead to inflation since inflation is a product of both total circulation as well as the _velocity_ by which it circulates (if you print money and just keep it under a mattress, it is not chasing goods, so theoretically should not affect prices). But of course it opens the possibility for inflation, which is what @Justin Cave notes is as a main drawback in the 1st paragraph of his answer.

Answer (score 1):

During the 2011 debt-ceiling crisis, some pundits encouraged the United States Treasury, based on the specific text in a law enabling the Treasury to produce platinum collectible coins (that happens to not prescribe coin denominations in the statute, when the metal used is platinum) to create a [trillion dollar coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillion-dollar_coin), deposit it in the Federal Reserve, and eliminate the debt ceiling restriction, a political impasse at the time.  There are experts of both political parties who believe this is an untested but legal path under the statute.

The Treasury (and all governments that issue money) has long collected [seignorage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seigniorage), the differential of the face value of coins over the cost to produce them.  The trillion dollar coin essentially would create a trillion dollars of seignorage; this is not a new concept for governments though this would be at a new order of magnitude.

Since 2011 there have been proposed laws to amend the collectible coin law, but it has not yet been changed by Congress.  What has kept it from happening is, basically, a political decision by the executive branch that it would be received badly by the electorate as a nutty-sounding, norm-breaking event.